# Can't create SendGrid resource with Azure CLI template - "Invalid subscription identifier provided"

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-cli

I'm not able to create a SendGrid resource in Azure using a JSON template - I get a `ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed` error. I am able to create other Azure resources e.g. storage.

To reproduce:

```
az login
az group create --name MyResourceGroup --location "uksouth"
az group deployment create `
  --name MyDeployment `
  --resource-group MyResourceGroup `
  --template-file template.json `
```

template.json:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
           "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
           "name": "mysendgrid",
           "type": "Sendgrid.Email/accounts",
           "location": "uksouth",
           "plan": {
              "name": "free",
              "publisher": "Sendgrid",
              "product": "sendgrid_azure",
              "promotionCode": ""
           },
           "properties": {
               "password": "mypassword",
               "acceptMarketingEmails": false,
               "email": "me@myemail.com",
               "firstName": "John",
               "lastName": "Smith",
               "company":"My Company",
               "website": "",
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

Error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed",
"message": "User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: '{\"error\":{\"code\":\"InvalidSubscriptionId\",\"message\":\"Invalid subscription identifier provided.\"}}'"
  }
```

I don't know how to provide any other subscription ID.

Comment: try creating the same resource through the portal, you might not have permissions. this looks fine, tbh

Comment: Any update now?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your account has more than one subscription and by default, you logging into a subscription that doesn't have access to the SendGrid?

You can display all your subscriptions using the command:

```
az account list
```

And then set the correct one:

```
az account set --subscription <name or id>
```

Comment: i dont think that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was some [problem at sendgrid end](https://github.com/sendgrid/docs/issues/5089#issuecomment-477747394). Since this is not a docs-related issue, please contact our Support team directly and they can help you out. You can access support contact options by logging into https://support.sendgrid.com.

You could try to point out subscription ID by add [`subscription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-deployment-create) parameters.

```
az group deployment create `
  --name MyDeployment `
  --resource-group MyResourceGroup `
  --template-file template.json `
  --subscription subId
```